# Find 2 equations from the given graph to get the 2 unknowns

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

[image]

The question is:

> The curve $(C')$ in the above figure is the represantative curve of the function $f$ defined over $]0,+\infty[$ by  $f(x)=\frac{a \ln x}{b+x}$.
>
> Find $a$ and $b$ knowing that $x=0$ is an asymptote to $(C')$ and that the area of the domain limited by $(C')$, the $x$-axis and the straight line of equation $x=2$ is $A=\frac{(\ln 2)^2}{2}$

I found 1 of the equations from the fact that $f'(1)=1$

But I tried to use the area and the curve and I didn't know how to integrate this function $f(x)$ from $x=1$ to $x=2$

And the asymptotes also didn't help and neither did the fact that $f(1)=0$

Can anyone help with the integral please? Or give another possible solution?

Comment: I am sorry, I will do that now

Comment: From the graph it seems that $f$ has a maximum at $x=2.$ From this you can get $b,$ then from $f'(1)$ you get $a$.

Comment: It seems so but its not true that it has a maximum at $2$. And usually if the maximum will be used they put it in the given or they show it clearly in the graph, but here they have given us the area so I think we must use it

Comment: What is xx' ? I don't know this notation.

Comment: The x-axis or the axis of abscissas

Answer (score 1):

Resume:

- As $x=0$ is an asymptote to $(C^{'}),$ necessarilly $b\geq0.$
- From $1=f'(1)=\frac{a}{b+1}$ we deduce $a=b+1.$

The function $g(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$ satisfies all constraints, because $\int_1^2 \frac{\ln x}{x} dx =\frac 12 (\ln 2)^2=\mathcal{A}.$ Here $b=0, a=1.$

But $$\frac{a\ln x}{b+x}-\frac{\ln x}{x}=\frac{(x-1)(a-1)\ln x}{x(b+x)}>0 \quad\text{for}\; x\in (1,2]\quad\text{and}\quad \;a=b+1> 1.$$
Therefore we have $$\int_1^2 \frac{a\ln x}{b+x} dx >\frac 12 (\ln 2)^2 \quad \text{if}\quad b>0.$$ The only convenient $b$ is $0$, and $a=1.$

Comment: I appreciate your help @user376343 I didn't quite understand what you want me to conclude at the end. Also this method of solving is like a trial and error way, can you try to find a more mathematical way to solve this? I mean without expecting what the right answer will be, and just getting it through some derivations and equations ...

Comment: This is surely not a trial - error. A function of given form with $b\neq0$ has a polylogarithm in the integral ... far from being probable in this kind of exercise. Thus it was reasonable to check the limit case $b=0.$ And then to find an argument for *why it must be this function*. This argument looks trivial now, when done :)

Comment: You mean that if they didn't put any given about the area, the exercise can still be solved? They usually only give the needed given to solve the exercise and not more, thats why I think that there must be another solution. I am thankful again and I am sorry for the many questions I am asking but can you please explain a bit more how you found out that $b=0$?

Comment: The area was important. Without, it would not be possible to exclude all possibilities except the one $b=0.$  I justified that in the case $b=0$ takes the area the given value, but in all other cases it is larger.

Comment: The area equals the integral of positive function.

Comment: Okay Thank you :) May I bother you with 1 more question please? If $b$ was another number the area would be larger you said, assume that $b=1$ for example, how can we get the integral of this function now? I mean how do you know it will be larger?

Comment: The integral is larger because the function with $b=1$ takes larger value than $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ for every $x\in (1,2],$ as I proved in my answer. [refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities ]